# 2003 Pontiac Bonneville - How to Remove Relays in Fusebox

Tags: pontiac, cooling-system, bonneville, relay

My grandparents have a 2003 Bonneville which has, in the past few months, started to become very wishy-washy with its air conditioning fans. They'll work one day, then not the next. They'll hit a bump in the road and then it will start working. They say its most affected by bumps on the right-hand side of the vehicle.

I went out and investigated a little, first deciding to check the fuses. All of the fuses seem to be in good shape, but there are three relays marked "Cooling Fan Relay" in the manual. After giving them a few medium taps with a wrench the air conditioning fan kicked on inside the car.

They're going to try it out for a while and make sure that it continues to work, but assuming that the problem returns--how am I supposed to remove these relays? I tried pulling on them with my hands, but couldn't get them out. They're square, two are gray, one is black.

Comment: A picture would be helpful

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pull them out with your hands, if it's the kind I am thinking of (in the fuse box under the hood) there is no latch or anything else holding them in.

Comment: I can't get a picture of it at the moment (my grandparents live some distance away). You've got the location right, and you can view a picture of what the part looks like [on the Advance Auto Parts website](http://shop.advanceautoparts.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_Relay-Factory-Air_18893215-P_588_R%7CGRPRELAAMS_611832723____). I don't know if its a four or five pin (as I couldn't get it out). For that matter, I don't even know if "cooling fan relay" is actually identifying the air conditioning fan or the radiator fan--but giving them a tap got the AC fan to run, none-the-less.